# Procedure parameter determines nested procedure parameter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am wanting to write a procedure that takes an invoice number and then outputs the details of the customer that bought that particular product.

I have a procedure that displays the details of the customer using a id number as a parameter and that works fine!

I don't know how to use the invoice number to determine the ID value for the customer procedure.

Am using Oracle, sql plus

## *Code:*

### Customer details procedure:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE custdets (in_number IN customers.c_ID%TYPE)
IS
    CURSOR customer_cursor
    IS
        SELECT c_ID,
               C_PH,
               c_FName,
               c_LName,
               c_address1,
               c_address2,
               c_address3
          FROM customers
         WHERE in_number = c_id;

    crow   customer_cursor%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR crow IN customer_cursor
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Customer Details');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
            'CUST ID#: ' || crow.c_id || CHR (9) || 'PH: ' || crow.c_ph);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
            'Customer Name: ' || crow.c_Fname || ',' || crow.c_Lname);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
               'Address: '
            || crow.c_address1
            || ','
            || crow.c_address2
            || ','
            || crow.c_address3);
    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

### Current Query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SalePurchase(in_invoice IN sales_purchases.sp_invoice%TYPE)
IS                      
BEGIN                     
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('###########################################');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('# P U R H A S E - S A L E - S U M M A R Y #');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('#         INVOICE NO: ' || in_invoice || '           #');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(chr(13)); 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('###########################################');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(13));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('############################################');
    custdets();
end;
/
```

Thanks in advance!

## Edit:

Have worked out that when i place an ID number in the procedure i want to call, eg custdets(4), it prints out the customer with the ID of that number. This is regardless of if they made the purchase or not.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh ummm Oracle, sql plus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Invoice number` should be the primary key of, I don't know, a table called INVOICES maybe? It's your schema, you know it better than we can. Anyhow, that table should have a column called `C_ID` or perhaps `customer_id` which is the ID of the customer being invoiced; that column is a foreign key to the CUSTOMERS table.

So, your new procedure must take Invoice ID as a parameter. Use that value to look up the INVOICES record. That will give you the C_ID to pass into your existing `custdets()` procedure and display the Customer details.

> "They are both in the same table how do i pass it it to custdets()"

Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SalePurchase(
      in_invoice IN sales_purchases.sp_invoice%TYPE)
IS          
    l_customer_id  sales_purchases.c_id%type;           
BEGIN  
    select c_id into l_customer_id
    from sales_purchases
    where sp_invoice = in_invoice;
    custdets(l_customer_id);
END;
```

Comment: The new procedure already takes the invoice ID number as a parameter as in_invoice. Are you saying that i have to put in_invoice in the brackets of custdets()?

Comment: No. You need to use the INVOICE ID to look up a record in the INVOICES table. My assumption is that you have an INVOICES table and that table has the CUSTOMER_ID. But it's **your data model** : I literally cannot see what tables you have or what their structures are. You are going to have to figure this out for yourself. But once you have the Customer ID for the invoice you need to pass that to `custdets()`.

Comment: the invoice ID is called sp_invoice and is in the sales_purchases table. the customer ID is called c_id and is a forigen key in the sales_purchases table.

Comment: So they are both in the same table how do i pass it it to custdets()?